# Кнопка показать ещё, после "перейти на страницу" и "вернутся назад", отображалась полностью предыдущая страница

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сайте есть каталог списка товаров. На странице отображается например 24 товара, постраничная навигация и кнопка **показать ещё**, которая подгружает новые товары по AJAX. Если пользователь нажимает например 9 раз кнопку **показать ещё**, то на странице будет отображено 10 страниц, т.е. 240 товаров.

Он переходит на один из товаров, потом нажимает кнопку в браузере **вернутся назад** и попадает на предыдущую начальную страницу и чтобы дойти до того же товара необходимо снова 9 раз нажать на кнопку **показать ещё**.

Как сделать так, чтобы когда пользователь нажимает **вернутся**, отображалось то состояние страницы, которое было перед этим (со всеми загруженными товарами)

Comment: так не пробовали <a onclick="javascript:history.back(); return false;">Назад</a>

Comment: обычно пользователь возвращается назад средствами браузера, как привык, а не ищет где же на странице кнопка назад

Answer (score 0):

Сохранять состояние (в сессиях, например) при нажатии на кнопку "показать ещё" и возобновлять при переходе на начальную страницу.

> (со всеми загруженными товарами)

А если юзер загрузит 1000 страниц? Правильнее перенаправлять пользователя на ту страницу, на которой тот самый последний товар отображается.

Comment: Согласен. Это нагрузка не только на пользователя но и на сервер. Только если автор создаст AJAX подгрузку информации о товаре и просто будет показывать ее "поверх" контента может быть это было бы полезно.

Comment: как раз вопрос и возник, как сделать так, чтобы заново не загружать все товары, так как такой запрос очень сильно тяжелый. подгрузка товаров по  AJAX. вроде так как нужно, реализовано в мобильной версии розетки m.rozetka.com.ua, но пока не разобрался, по какому принципу там работает.

Comment: можно сделать так: при переходе на страницу со списком товаров загружать ту часть товаров, которую в последний раз просматривал пользователь, а при прокрутке скролла вверх или вниз подргужать товары.